# Opoid addiction telltale signs

Tags: addiction, pain-management, opioids-opiates, substance-abuse

If one is taking prescription opioids to manage backpain from an auto accident, what is the litmus test \ telltale sign that one is becoming addicted?

What countermeasures can be taken to avoid addiction besides totally abstaining usage of opioids?

If you have experience working with addiction or have gone through the process of being addicted please state this in your reply.